# Python Libtorrent: Pausing torrent not working as expected

Tags: libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am trying to use Python-Libtorrent to download torrents. I have an issue where pausing the torrent doesn't work as expected:

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time

import sys


def get_libtorrent_session_and_start_dht(start_port, end_port):
    ses = lt.session()
    ses.listen_on(start_port, end_port)
    ses.add_dht_router('dht.transmissionbt.com', start_port)
    ses.add_dht_router('router.bittorrent.com', start_port)
    ses.add_dht_router('router.utorrent.com', start_port)
    ses.start_dht()
    return ses


const_state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
                   'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']
const_pause_torrent = "pause_torrent"
const_resume_torrent = "resume_torrent"
const_kill_torrent = "kill_torrent"
const_user_logged_in = "user_logged_in"
const_user_logged_out = "user_logged_out"
const_quit_seeding = "quit_seeding"

ses = get_libtorrent_session_and_start_dht(6881, 6891)

torrent_info = None
torrent_handle = None
try:
    torrent_info = lt.torrent_info("/home/horvste/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent")
    torrent_handle = ses.add_torrent(
        {'ti': torrent_info, 'save_path': "/home/horvste/Downloads"})
except Exception as exception:
    raise exception

while not torrent_handle.has_metadata():
    print "Getting meta data"
    time.sleep(1)

current_iteration = 0
while not torrent_handle.is_seed():
    torrent_status = torrent_handle.status()

    print "current_iteration: " + str(current_iteration)

    if current_iteration == 10:
        print "Calling torrent_handle.pause()...Pausing Torrent"
        sys.stdout.flush()
        torrent_handle.pause()
        while not torrent_handle.status().paused:
            print "Torrent Is Not Paused Yet"
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        while torrent_handle.status().paused:
            print "Torrent Is Paused!"
            torrent_handle.pause()
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.flush()


    if const_state_str[torrent_status.state] == "checking":
        print 'Checking Torrent....'
        continue

    print '\r%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % \
          (torrent_status.progress * 100, torrent_status.download_rate / 1000, torrent_status.upload_rate / 1000, \
           torrent_status.num_peers, const_state_str[torrent_status.state]), \
        sys.stdout.flush()

    current_iteration += 1

    if torrent_status.paused:
        print "Is Paused"
    else:
        print "Is Not Paused"

    time.sleep(1)
```

Here is this scripts output:

```
...Previous Output Checking Torrent
Checking Torrent....
current_iteration: 0
4.17% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 0) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 1
4.17% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 0) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 2
4.17% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 4) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 3
4.17% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 7) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 4
4.17% complete (down: 1.0 kb/s up: 1.0 kB/s peers: 11) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 5
4.17% complete (down: 4.0 kb/s up: 2.0 kB/s peers: 16) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 6
4.17% complete (down: 52.0 kb/s up: 5.0 kB/s peers: 21) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 7
4.17% complete (down: 132.0 kb/s up: 8.0 kB/s peers: 28) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 8
4.26% complete (down: 234.0 kb/s up: 12.0 kB/s peers: 33) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 9
4.31% complete (down: 317.0 kb/s up: 15.0 kB/s peers: 38) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 10
Calling torrent_handle.pause()...Pausing Torrent
Torrent Is Paused!
Torrent Is Paused!
Torrent Is Paused!
4.31% complete (down: 418.0 kb/s up: 19.0 kB/s peers: 46) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 11
4.44% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 12
4.44% complete (down: 0.0 kb/s up: 1.0 kB/s peers: 12) downloading None
Is Not Paused
current_iteration: 13
4.44% complete (down: 1.0 kb/s up: 2.0 kB/s peers: 21) downloading None
...Torrent keeps downloading
```

As you can see from the above script, I call pause on the torrent handle and it pauses for 3 iterations of the loop and starts downloading again. It is important to note that the previous script did not have the `torrent_handle.pause()` call in this while loop:

```
while torrent_handle.status().paused:
    print "Torrent Is Paused!"
    torrent_handle.pause()
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am still getting the same output; the torrent doesn't pause as expected. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.4 and everything is installed via apt-get. In the libtorrent init.py my version number is `version = '0.16.13.0'`. Am I missing something or misusing the library?

Comment: there's a "NOTE" box in the documentation for torrent_handle::pause()

Answer (score 2):

Torrents are auto managed by default and that could bring them out of pause, check flags in add_torrent_params